# The import org.apache.hadoop cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, hadoop, importerror

I have seen this asked but none of the fixes seem to be working for me. Or more likely I am doing it wrong as I am very new to this.

(Working in eclipse) I get the error `The import org.apache.hadoop cannot be resolved` on the following lines:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
```

I *thought* I'd added the correct external jars but apparently not. The ones I have are below. I added them by going to Properties of my project, Java Build Path, Libraries, Add External Jar

`commons-codec-1.9.jar
    commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
    commons-io-2.4-javadoc.jar
    commons-io-2.4-sources.jar
    commons-io-2.4-testsources.jar
    commons-io-2.4-tests.jar
    commons-io-2.4.jar
    commons-logging-1.2.jar
    fluent-hc-4.4.jar
    httpclient-4.4.jar
    httpclient-cache-4.4.jar
    httpclient-win-4.4.jar
    httpcore-4.4.jar
    httpmime-4.4.jar
    jna-4.1.0.jar
    jna-platform-4.1.0.jar`

Comment: Try this and you can save some time adding all the jars and might remove the errors as well

http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/03/03/how-to-install-eclipse-hadoopmap-reduce-2-x-plugin-on-linuxunix-easy-guide/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to still be missing dependencies.

Hadoop development is not trivial, there are a lot of dependencies and it can get messy very fast. Why not use a dependency manager like Maven? You could then simply add this to your POM.xml and let it do the hard work for you:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not familiar with Maven, there are tons of information available on SO and elsewhere about how to setup basic Maven projects with Eclipse!

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Yes, I was still missing dependencies. I'm unfamiliar with Maven but tutorials got me through. Thanks so much!